# Better pattern/design for this java code?

Tags: java

LinkedIn rest API for people search has following format `http://api.linkedin.com/people-search?search-param1=val1&search-param2=val2...`

Since I intend to use this many time in my application, I am trying to create a `Search` object like this where we can set values for different search parameters and then a method called `generateQueryUrl` to generate the url in above format.

```
public class Search {
  private String searchParam1;
  private String searchParam2;

  public void setSearchParam1(String val) { this.searchParam1 = val; }
  public void setSearchParam2(String val) { this.searchParam2 = val; }

  //Form the query url
  public String generateQueryUrl(){
    String url = "";  
    if(searchParam1 != null) {
        url += "search-param1=" +  searchParam1 + "&";
    }
    if(searchParam2 != null) {
        url += "search-param2=" +  searchParam2 + "&";
    }
    return url;
 }
```

My question is, is there a better pattern/design to do this? If there are many parameters, checking for `NULL` and then appending corresponding parameter name, value seems to add redundant code to me.

Also please let me know if this approach is fine.

Comment: please ignore minor flaws like extra & sign at end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are designing is in fact a "Builder", in that you are building the URL that will be returned at the end. Think `StringBuilder`, or Apache's `EqualsBuilder`, `HashCodeBuilder`, etc.

For a more theoretical explanation, check http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder.

Now, as for your code, to properly build the URL, I would use "set" methods like you do, but inside them I would use Apache's [HttpComponents (ex HttpClient)](http://hc.apache.org/index.html) to properly append the parameters of the URL.

Think about it, if you insert a "&" in the value of one of the parameter, your query parameters will be messed up since you normally have to escape this character (and you don't seem to be doing it here). I prefer letting tested and known APIs (UriUtils) do that for me.

So, my class would look like so using Apache's HttpComponents:

```
public class SearchBuilder {
  private URI baseUri;
  private List<NameValuePair> parameters;

  public SearchBuilder (URI baseUri) {
    this.baseUri= baseUri;
    this.parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  }

  public void addSearchParam1(String val) { 
    if(!StringUtils.isBlank(val)) {
      parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SearchParam1", val));
    }
  }

  //Form the query url
  public URI toURI(){
    URI uri = URIUtils.createURI(baseUri.getScheme(), baseUri.getHost(), baseUri.getPort(), baseUri.getPath(), URLEncodedUtils.format(parameters, "UTF-8"), null);
    return uri;
  }
```

Edit: I added the "isBlank" check to ensure that parameters with null, empty of whitespace-only Strings will not be added to the query. Now, you can change that to check only for null, but I'm sure you got the idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can maintain a Map with keys as the param names and values as the values. Your setter methods can put keys and values in the Map. Or, you can have one generic setter which accepts the name & the value.
In the generateQueryUrl method, you can just iterate over the Map.

You may also want to URLEncode the values if not being done at the later stage.